# Update component outside of h:form - ComponentNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I am trying to update the element "entryDiv" in my xhtml from a button inside a form like this:

```
<div id="entryDiv">    
    <div>                              
        <h:form id="myForm">
            <c:forEach items="#{foodPlanManagementBean.loadRestaurantsHistory()}" var="restaurantHistoryEntry">
                    <p:commandButton value="MyName" update="entryDiv"/>
            </c:forEach>
        </h:form>
    </div>

    Some more unrelated elements here...
</div>
```

However, this way all I am left with is a ComponentFoundException, tell me that the component could not be located:

```
Cannot find component for expression "entryDiv" referenced from "form:myForm:j_idt25".
```

I already read up a bit on SO and I found one solution proposing to put a `:` in front of the "entryDiv", but that doesn't turn out to give me any different results.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSF can't see the id of your div if it is not a JSF component so you need to convert your div to a `h:panelGroup`

```
 <h:panelGroup id="entryDiv" layout="block">
     <div>                              
        <h:form id="myForm">
            <c:forEach items="#{foodPlanManagementBean.loadRestaurantsHistory()}" var="restaurantHistoryEntry">
                    <p:commandButton value="MyName" update=":entryDiv"/>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </h:form>
    </div>
  </h:panelGroup>
```

if you don't put `layout="block"` it will render a span instead of a div.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sadly, I'm still getting the error, even after replacing my div with a panelGroup

Comment: @Sossenbinder in this case you need to add the `:`

Comment: Thats what I thought as well, but even that doesn't change a thing :(

Are the parent elements of the "entryDiv"-panelGroup of any significance?

Comment: @Sossenbinder it shouldnt matter are they h:panelGroup too? why dont you try updating the root parent?

Comment: @Sossenbinder there is this tag `</div>`  below the button is that ok ?</div>

Comment: @Sossenbinder i think i found the bug, try with a `p:panel` instead of the `h:panelGroup` and remove `layout="block"` and let me know.

Comment: I fixed the mistake on my own. My own stupidity which was not displayed in this code, sorry :) Your answer was correct